# Updating all fields in a Word document except those of type wdFieldDocVariable

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a procedure which updates all fields in a document.
However I would like to skip the wdFieldDocVariable, the item index should be Type.

```
Public Sub MyApplicationUpdate()
hdWriteInfoLog ("BEGIN MACRO:   MyApplicationUpdate")
Dim oTOC As TableOfContents
Dim oField As Field

' Update Fields in all document StoryRanges
Dim oStory As Range
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    oStory.Fields.Update
    If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
        While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
            oStory.Fields.Update
        Wend
    End If
Next oStory
Set oStory = Nothing

' Update all TablesOfContents
For Each oTOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
    oTOC.Update
Next oTOC

hdWriteInfoLog ("END MACRO:     MyApplicationUpdate")
End Sub
```

Comment: What's the item index of `wdFieldDocVariable` in `OStory`?

Comment: I believe it should be something like "If Not oStory.Type = wdFieldDocVariable Then"?

Comment: What's `wdFieldDocVariable`? What's assigned into it?

Comment: I have assigned some address fields into it, I just need to skip all variables of this type when updating.

Comment: What's the Index of those address fields? Can you supply the line in?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I have found the answer, I believe there is a more efficient way of doing this, but at least it works...

' Test procedure
Public Sub MyApplicationUpdate()
    hdWriteInfoLog ("BEGIN MACRO:   MyApplicationUpdate")
    Dim oTOC As TableOfContents
    Dim oField As Field
    Dim oField2 As Field

```
' Update Fields in all document StoryRanges
Dim oStory As Range
For Each oStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    For Each oField2 In oStory.Fields
        If Not oField2.Type = wdFieldDocVariable Then
            oField2.Update
        End If
    Next oField2

    If oStory.StoryType <> wdMainTextStory Then
        While Not (oStory.NextStoryRange Is Nothing)
            Set oStory = oStory.NextStoryRange
            ' oStory.Fields.Update
            For Each oField2 In oStory.Fields
                If Not oField2.Type = wdFieldDocVariable Then
                    oField2.Update
                End If
            Next oField2
        Wend
    End If
Next oStory
Set oStory = Nothing

' Update all TablesOfContents
For Each oTOC In ActiveDocument.TablesOfContents
    oTOC.Update
Next oTOC

hdWriteInfoLog ("END MACRO:     MyApplicationUpdate")
```

End Sub